# Necessary to escape a java regular expression in matches()?

Tags: java

I'm currently doing a test on an HTTP Origin to determine if it came from SSL:

```
(HttpHeaders.Names.ORIGIN).matches("/^https:\\/\\//")
```

But I'm finding it's not working. Do I need to escape `matches()` strings like a regular expression or can I leave it like `https://`? Is there any way to do a simple string match?

Seems like it would be a simple question, but surprisingly I'm not getting anywhere even after using a RegEx tester http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's regex doesn't need delimiters. Simply do:

```
.matches("https://.*")
```

Note that matches validates the entire  input string, hence the `.*` at the end. And if the input contains line break chars (which `.` will *not* match), enable DOT-ALL:

```
.matches("(?s)https://.*")
```

Of couse, you could also simply do:

```
.startsWith("https://")
```

which takes a plain string (no regex pattern).

Answer (score 0):

How about this Regex:

```
"^(https:)\/\/.*"
```

It works in your tester

Comment: This doesn't even compile as a legal Java string. There's no point in the capture group and there's no point in the explicit ^ since `matches` always checks the whole string.